# CodeIgniter Active Record Where Not In String

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having an issue with CI Active Record's "**Where Not In**". I am trying to exclude a series of ID's. I couldn't understand why everything worked fine and dandy with **one** record, but not with multiple.

**My Query**

```
$this->db->where_not_in('crm.user_id', $ignore);
```

The problem is when I **profile** the the Query is wrong.

**With a string of ID's**

```
// $ignore = "12,13";    
SELECT *
FROM (`crm`)
WHERE `crm`.`user_id` NOT IN ('16,13') 
AND `survey` =  1
```

**With a string of Quotes ID's**

```
// $ignore = "'12','13'";
SELECT *
FROM (`crm`)
WHERE `crm`.`user_id` NOT IN ('\'16\',\'13\'') 
AND `survey` =  1
```

Am I forced to do a loop of "**or_where_not_in**" or something like that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`where_in` and `where_not_in` expect you to pass an array, not a string as the 2nd parameter.

```
$ignore = array(12, 13);

$this->db->where_not_in('crm.user_id', $ignore);
```

Link to the docs: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html