# How can I simplify this query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

If you look at the following query:

```
$query = $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->from('sets')
        ->where('type', 'd')
        ->or_where('type', 'e')
        ->or_where('type', 'f')
        ->or_where('type', 'g')
        ->or_where('type', 'h')
        ->or_where('type', 'i')
        ->or_where('type', 'j')
        ->or_where('type', 'k')
        ->or_where('type', 'l')
        ->or_where('type', 'm')

                    ...

        ->or_where('type', 'x')
        ->or_where('type', 'y')
        ->or_where('type', 'z')
        ->order_by('date', 'asc');

    return $query->get()->result();
```

In the 'type' column I have 'a' through 'z' bascially I would like all rows minus the ones with a, b, c. How can I write this in a more elegant way?

Comment: Not sure whether CI's DBAL supports it but in mysql there is `BETWEEN`. Otherwise you could create it yourself using `IN` and an `implode` of the PHP `range()` function result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want "basically all rows **except** those with a, b or c", you can make use of the `where_not_in` directive:

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('sets')
    ->where_not_in('type', array('a','b','c'))
    ->order_by('date', 'asc');
```

See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673933/codeigniter-active-record-where-not-in-string) (beware of the arrays!)

## Update

Just to add spice, the question whether to use `where_in` or `where_not_in` is not actually so simple ("*just use the one which will generate the shortest/simplest SQL*"). If you have a large table and the cardinality of the sets you're going to look for is large, **and** you have an index on the field, *then* (depending on many factors) doing a **negative** search might be far less efficient than an (apparently) larger **positive** search.

Indexes are good at looking for what's **in** them, not for what's *not* in them. So you might actually find it beneficial to do:

```
->where_in('type', array_diff(  // Where type is...
    range('a', 'z'),            // ...everything...
    array('a','b','c')          // EXCEPT a, b or c
))

// The above solution works also if you look for non-consecutive letters.
```

MySQL might then do twenty *very fast index lookups* (d, e, f, ...), instead of only three compares on a *possibly slow full table scan*. Depending on how many items you're looking for, the indexing, disk performances, table size and (did I leave out the weather?) the weather, this second method might be faster even if the SQL is more complicated.

It's surely something to look at when you'll be in the query optimizing stage. *Don't* just go and index every column as you'll see suggested in some online so-called *tutorials* -- indexing can sometimes be *harmful* to performances, and overindexing by definition always is.

Comment: it would be where_in instead

Comment: +1 You could use `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM foo WHERE type IN (a,b,c))` Which would invert the negative search into a positive one.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
$query = $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->from('sets')

        ->where_in('type', range('d','z'))

        ->order_by('date', 'asc');

    return $query->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sets where type not in ('a','b','c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of the characters from d to z like:

```
$chars = array('d', 'e'...., 'z');
```

Now, use `where_in` clause like this:

```
$rs = $this->db->select('')->where_in('type', $chars)->get('table');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('type !=', 'a');
$this->db->where('type !=', 'b');
$this->db->where('type !=', 'c');
$this->db->order_by('date', 'asc');
$query = $this->db->get('sets');
```

This should work.

Also note there is no need to use SELECT or FROM when selecting everything and using GET.