# Codeigniter MySQL Query with Variables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to run the following sample query in Codeigniter

```
SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.game_id
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN
(SELECT banned.users_id FROM banned) AND game_id = '1'
ORDER BY last_name
```

Now this works fine in MySQL, however I would require the following to be variables (game_id, '1', last_name) so that I can do the following

**MODEL**

```
function get_where_custom_ordered_checked($col, $value, $order_by) {

        $query = $this->db->query('
                                    SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.game_id
                                    FROM users
                                    WHERE users.id NOT IN
                                    (SELECT banned.users_id FROM banned) AND $col = $value
                                    ORDER BY $order_by
                                    ');
        return $query;
    }
```

Obviously this doesn't work, and the query doesn't recognise the variable. How would I achieve this? I have also tried using SET as shown in my research like the following (but still no avail).

**MODEL**

```
function get_where_custom_ordered_checked($col, $value, $order_by) {
        $query1 = 'SET @col = '$col', @value = '$value', @order_by = '$order_by'';
        $this->db->query($query1);
        $query2 = $this->db->query('
                                    SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.game_id
                                    FROM users
                                    WHERE users.id NOT IN
                                    (SELECT players_phases.players_id FROM players_phases) AND @col = @value
                                ORDER BY @order_by
                                    ');
        $query = $this->db->query($query2);
        return $query;
    }
```

Now I've tried breaking it down instead to use the Codeigniter Active Record Class,  but I don't know how to include the where_not_in() inside a where(), especially since I need to run the NOT IN query against a second table - unlike the where_not_in() examples shown in the Active Records CI documentation where it is against the same table.

Any advice or assistance would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Active Record Where Not In String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673933/codeigniter-active-record-where-not-in-string)

Comment: can explain in more and what you achieve ?

Comment: You can also use string interpolation. If you need variable read within a string, use double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code. Generally anything which is given within the single quotes consider as a string, so it doesn't recognize the variables.

```
function get_where_custom_ordered_checked($col, $value, $order_by) {

    $query = $this->db->query('
                                SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.game_id
                                FROM users
                                WHERE users.id NOT IN
                                (SELECT banned.users_id FROM banned) AND '.$col.' = '.$value.'
                                ORDER BY '.$order_by.'
                                ');
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your insight. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP you cannot use variables in single quotes, they won't be recognized.

Use the following code instead:

```
'SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.game_id
 FROM users
 WHERE users.id NOT IN
 (SELECT players_phases.players_id FROM players_phases) AND ' . $col . ' = ' . $value . 'ORDER BY @order_by'
```

Let me know if this is working for you.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your insight. Much appreciated.